# Filling and saving shared buffer between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, circular-buffer

I'm working with an API that retrieves I/Q data. Calling the function `bbGetIQ(m_handle, &pkt);`fills a buffer. This is a thread looping while the user hasn't input "stop". Pkt is a structure and the buffer used is `pkt.iqData = &m_buffer[0];` which is a vector of float. The size of the vector is 5000 and each time we're looping the buffer is filled with 5000 values.

I want to save the data from the buffer into a file, and I was doing it right after a call to `bbgetIQ` but doing like so is a time consuming task, data wasn't retrieved fast enough resulting in the API dropping data so it can continue filling its buffer.

Here's what my code looked like :

```cpp
void Acquisition::recordIQ(){

    int cpt = 0;
    ofstream myfile;


    while(1){

        while (keep_running)
        {   

            cpt++;

            if(cpt < 2)
                myfile.open ("/media/ssd/IQ_Data.txt");


            bbGetIQ(m_handle, &pkt); //Retrieve I/Q data


            //Writing content of buffer into the file.
            for(int i=0; i<m_buffer.size(); i++)
                myfile << m_buffer[i] << endl;


        }
        cpt = 0;
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

Then i tried to only write into the file when we leave the loop :

```cpp
void Acquisition::recordIQ(){

    int cpt = 0;
    ofstream myfile;
    int next=0;
    vector<float> data;


    while(1){

        while ( keep_running)
        {   
            if(keep_running == false){

                myfile.open ("/media/ssd/IQ_Data.txt");

                for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
                    myfile << data[i] << endl;

                myfile.close();
                break;
            }

            cpt++;

            data.resize(next + m_buffer.size());

            bbGetIQ(m_handle, &pkt); //retrieve data

            std::copy(m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.end(), data.begin() + next); //copy content of the buffer into final vector

            next += m_buffer.size(); //next index

        }

        cpt = 0;

    }
}
```

I am no longer getting data loss from the API, but the issue is that i'm limited by the size of `data` vector. For example, I can't let it retrieve data all night.

My idea is to make 2 threads. One will retrieve data and the other will write the data into a file. The 2 threads will share a circular buffer where the first thread will fill the buffer and the second thread will read the buffer and write the content to a file. As it is a shared buffer, i guess i should use mutexes.

I'm new to multi-threading and mutex, so would this be a good idea? I don't really know where to start and how the consumer thread can read the buffer while the producer will fill it. Will locking the buffer while reading cause data drop by the API ? (because it won't be able to write it into the circular buffer).

**EDIT** : As i want my record thread to run in background so i can do other stuff while it's recording, i detached it and the user can launch a record by setting the condition `keep_running` to true.

```cpp
thread t1(&Acquisition::recordIQ, &acq);
t1.detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

globals:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::vector<std::vector<float>> datas;
bool keep_running = true, start_running = false;
```

writing thread:

```
void writing_thread()
{
    myfile.open ("/media/ssd/IQ_Data.txt");

    while(1) {
        // Wait until main() sends data
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return keep_running && !datas.empty();});
        if (!keep_running) break;

        auto d = std::move(datas); 
        lk.unlock();

        for(auto &entry : d) {
            for(auto &e : entry)
                myfile << e << endl;             
        }
    }
}
```

sending thread:

```
void sending_thread() {
    while(1) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            cv.wait(lk, []{return keep_running && start_running;});
            if (!keep_running) break;
        }

        bbGetIQ(m_handle, &pkt); //retrieve data

        std::vector<float> d = m_buffer;

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
            if (!keep_running) break;
            datas.push_back(std::move(d));
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}
void start() {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        start_running = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}
void stop() {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        start_running = false;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}
void terminate() {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        keep_running = false;
    }
    cv.notify_all();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```

In short:
Sending thread receives data from whatever it comes, locks mutex `mt` and moves data to `datas` storage. Then it uses `cv` condition variable to notify waiting threads, that there's something to do. Writing thread waits for condition variable to be signaled, then locks mutex `mt`, **moves** data from `datas` global variable to local, then **releases** mutex and proceed to write just received data to file. Key is to keep mutexed locked for least time possible.

EDIT:
to terminate whole thing you need to set `keep_running` to false. **Then** call `cv.notify_all()`. **Then** join threads involved. Order is important. You need to join threads, because writing thread might be still in process of writing data.

EDIT2:
added delayed start. Now create two threads, in one run `sending_thread`, in other `writing_thread`. Call `start()` to enable processing and `stop()` to stop it.

Comment: So if I understand well, sending thread will never stop ? It will keep receiving and moving data then notify the writing thread which will be the only one waiting? Also do i have to take care of the `keep _running` condition as it is used for the two threads?

Comment: Set the condition to false, **then** use `cv.notify_all()`, **then** join threads (wait for thread destruction) and it's done. Order matters. You need to join threads to wait for them to finish, as writing thread might be still in process of writing data.

Comment: The things is that i want my sending thread to work in background because i'm doing other operations in parallel. That's why i detached it and "activate" it when i need to retrieve data with the `keep_running`condition.

Comment: Ok, i'm starting to understand ! Will this work with a detached thread? Because if i'm joining sending thread it will block the main thread until sending thread terminates and I won't be able to make other processing while sending thread is active. Edit : it seems like you have brackets issue in your code.

Comment: Not sure, what dfo you mean by detached thread. Currently you can just create two threads and let them be. When you're ready to call `bbGetIQ`, call my function `start()`, when you want to stop processing, call `stop()`. The threads will be still there ready, but waiting, thus not consuming any processor time. When you decide to exit your application, then you've to execute this termination procedure. I will add `terminate()` just for good measure.

Comment: What I mean by "detached" is to call `std::thread::detach` to allow execution of the thread to continue independently. Because calling `std::thread::join` will force the program to wait for the thread to terminate and i wouldn't be able to continue the execution of the main until sending thread is terminated

Comment: You don't need to detach to keep it running independently. You don't have to call join at all, but you risk loosing some data, when you finally decide to end your program.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help ! Because i read that for threads, if we don't call either `join`or `detach`it will call `std::terminate` if the flow of execution reaches the destructor. So i may use detach to be safe ?

Comment: I'm trying to test your code but i didn't manage to make it work. This is what the compiler tells me : "error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<float>::push_back(std::remove_reference<float*>::type)" at the line `datas.push_back(std::move(d));` in sending thread. I guess it's because we use `push_back` on the whole vector d. Writing thread when writing into the file i get the following error : "error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope" same with 'end'.

Comment: That question requires minimal, working example. Can you post it on some online compiler / editor and post a link?

Comment: You need `std::vector<std::vector<float>> datas;`. You used `std::vector<float> datas;`.

Comment: Also what are the braces `{
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        start_running = true;
    }` used for? It's the first time i'm seeing this syntax. Thank you for your help, didn't pay attention to datas vector.

Comment: Those braces create new scope. Scope is like dictionary for identifiers. Any variable defined in a scope is destroyed, when scope ends. This scope is used to make sure `lk` will be destroyed at `}` (as quickly as possible, since `lk` locks mutex `m`).

Comment: Ok, i get it,  Thanks !

Comment: Should i always create a new scope when using locks and mutexes ?

Comment: No. The scope created is only to destroy lock sooner.  For example on beginning of `sending_thread` i destroy lock as soon as possible, then call `bbGetIQ`, which might take a while. Then i once again reacquire the lock, push the data and destroy the lock immediately.

Comment: So i tried to implement your code to fit my use and it kind of works. The issue is that in `sending_thread` i put a cout `IN333` and the program is working but when i comment this line the program crashes with the error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc". Also when the program is working, all the data is not copied, each loop i know there is 50 floats copied. So i multiply 50*number_of_loops to know the total of data copied. But in the output file i notice that there is missing data. Could you please look at my code? http://cpp.sh/8lb5f